# Team city agent service dont have internet connection

Tags: windows-services, teamcity, testcomplete

I setup continious integration on my project using teamcity+testcomplete+jscript.

Teamcity builds are runned by command line script. But when it started I have pop up windows service message on agent machine -"A program running on this computer is trying to display a message" when I click "View the message"
 As I understand I go to windows service desktop and there I see that my framework starts and tests running but when Internet explorere browser is opened for running tests there are no internet connection, for any sites. Localy on this pc internet is available.

Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Check the user that the TeamCity BuildAgent Service is running under. If it is one of the system users, it is locked out from the network. If that is so, try specifying a more normal user for the service, one that would have network access. Remember to pick one with low access or you're probably going to have to remember changing the password for the user whenever it expires.

Comment: thx, I will try ti use another account, really apreciate

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen
I asked my sys admin to provide his username and password during installation, so teamcity agent was installed with help of his account. And now when I trying to trigger teamcity run nothing happen, is it because I loged under my account? but I added his credential into local security policy